# jquery datepicker : Need to enable a few weekends from already disabled weekends

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a code where by I have disabled a few dates and all the weekends in the jQuery datepicker. Now there is a requirement that I have to enable a few weekend dates.

I have tried adding in those dates to an array and then try to enable them but it's not working. I need a solution to this problem. Current code is below which works fine for disabling weekends and a certain set of dates. Please let me know how can I add code for enabling a couple of Sundays in the month of May or June (for instance 28-05-2017)

```
<script>
var unavailableDates = ["16-9-2017", "22-9-2017" , "19-10-2017", "1-12-2017" , "11-12-2017" , "25-12-2017", "1-1-2018" , "31-1-2018" , "16-2-2018" , "17-2-2018" , "1-5-2018"];

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: +2, beforeShowDay:noSunday, numberOfMonths:2, 
       onSelect: function(date, obj){
           $('#date_input').val(date);  //Updates value of of your input 
       }
    });

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");

    function noSunday(date){ 
        var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        var day = date.getDay();
        if (day == 0) {
            return [false, "Highlighted", date];
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < unavailableDates.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) != -1 ) {
                return [false, "Highlighted", date];
            }
        }
        return [true, '', ''];
    };
});
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of your returns in your beforeShowDay function wasn't returning a valid array. From the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay), it states:

> [2] an optional popup tooltip for this date

```
if (day == 0) {
    return [false, "Highlighted"];
}
```

Whilst your loop and usage of `inArray` would have worked, you have already done the difficult part of creating the String representation of the Calendar's date, to match the format of the Dates within your Array.

I used [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to identify if the String existed in the Dates array.  If it didn't, return `[true, '']`, otherwise, return the false state `[false, "Highlighted"]`.

```js
var unavailableDates = ["16-9-2017", "22-9-2017", "19-10-2017", "1-12-2017", "11-12-2017", "25-12-2017", "1-1-2018", "31-1-2018", "16-2-2018", "17-2-2018", "1-5-2018"];

$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: +2,
    beforeShowDay: noSunday,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(date, obj) {
      $('#date_input').val(date); //Updates value of of your input 
    }
  });

  $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");

  function noSunday(date) {
    var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    var day = date.getDay();
    if (day == 0) {
      return [false, "Highlighted"];
    } else {
      return (unavailableDates.indexOf(dmy) !== -1) ? [false, "Highlighted"] : [true, ''];
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep same Sundays enabled you can simply change the if condition that you are using for disabling them. Instead of:

```
if (day == 0)
```

use

```
if (day == 0 && $.inArray(dmy, availableDates) == -1)
```

where `availableDates` is an Array that contains all the Sundays that you want to keep enabled.

Here a live sample:

```js
var unavailableDates = ["16-9-2017", "22-9-2017" , "19-10-2017", "1-12-2017" , "11-12-2017" , "25-12-2017", "1-1-2018" , "31-1-2018" , "16-2-2018" , "17-2-2018" , "1-5-2018"];

var availableDates = ["28-5-2017"];

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  minDate: +2,
  beforeShowDay: noSunday,
  numberOfMonths:2, 
  onSelect: function(date, obj){
    $('#date_input').val(date);  //Updates value of of your input 
  },
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});

function noSunday(date){ 
  var dmy = $.datepicker.formatDate("d-m-yy", date);
  
  var day = date.getDay();
  if (day == 0 && $.inArray(dmy, availableDates) == -1) {
    return [false, "Highlighted"];
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < unavailableDates.length; i++) {
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) != -1 ) {
      return [false, "Highlighted"];
    }
  }
  return [true, ''];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" id="date_input">
```

Note that:

- I've used [`dateFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) option when initializing the datepicker
- I've used `$.datepicker.formatDate` to format date in the `"d-m-yy"` format.
- I've removed the third optional *tooltip* parameter from the [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) function.